# Enabling ClamAV in PrimeFaces FileUpload component

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

As PrimeFaces documentantions says, to enable ClamAV in FileUpload we just need:

- `virusScan="true"` in component
- `primefaces.virusscan.CLAMAV_HOST` context param in web.xml
- `primefaces.virusscan.CLAMAV_PORT` context param in web.xml

This is all fine, but ClamAV isn't called.

I enabled PF logging, and the output is:

```
[org.primefaces.virusscan.VirusScannerService] Performing virus scan...
[org.primefaces.virusscan.VirusScannerService] Skipping virus scan with org.primefaces.virusscan.impl.VirusTotalReportScanner provider since it is disabled
[org.primefaces.virusscan.VirusScannerService] No virus detected
```

As we can see [VirusScannerService](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/virusscan/VirusScannerService.java) do not list [ClamAV](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/virusscan/impl/ClamDaemonScanner.java) service as an option.

VirusScannerService uses java.util.ServiceLoader to find services available in class loader.

Any clues why it can't load the service?

PrimeFaces 11.0.

Comment: what implementations of VirusScanner are available on the class path? those need to be ServiceLoader enabled first

Comment: What version of PF are you using?  ClamAV was not added until 10.0.0 ?

Comment: See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5654

Comment: Sorry, @Melloware. Forgot this... PF 11

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher. Both implementations available in classparh, they are default in PF 11.

Comment: OK let me investigate and see if its a bug.  It should try both of them checking their "isEnabled" function.  I will report back what I find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK its a bug but there is a workaround.

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8812

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/8813

To fix this right now... register the service provider just place a file named `org.primefaces.virusscan.VirusScanner` in the `META-INF/services` directory of your WAR.

Make sure it contains this single line:

```
org.primefaces.virusscan.impl.ClamDaemonScanner
```